# Akka spawn thread using Semahpore

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka-stream

I'm new to multithreading, I'm using Akka Stream to process few files concurrently, based on the below code, multiple threads
are spawned, the memory gets full and the OS kills the process.
I also tried the fix the number of threads using FixedThreadPool and Akka dispatchers
I want the thread to acquire permit before spawning,
I looking for a Semaphore like feature to implement using Akka, I'm having trouble figuring out
in Akka ?

```
val execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)
implicit val execContext: ExecutionContextExecutorService = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(execService)
val actorSystem = ActorSystem("myActor")
implicit val materializer = Materializer.createMaterializer(actorSystem)

val events = Source(inputs)
      .mapAsync(2)(timeConsumingProcess)
val parallelProcess = events.run()
parallelProcess.onComplete { _ =>
      actorSystem.terminate()
      materializer.shutdown()
    }
```

Comment: what does the memory gets full mean?. What is the exception you are getting? what kind of source is inputs?

Comment: used memory (RAM) and exception is OutOfMemory and source is a list of file paths, the "timeConsuming" process read the file content, does some processing and writes the output @EmilianoMartinez

Comment: Most likely your `timeConsumingProcess` is completely broken.  When are you completing the `Future` in `timeConsumingProcess`?

Comment: 10 seconds on average, and also I checked the memory used by each process using ```htop``` command, each process occupies 256MB

Comment: yes you are correct, there was something wrong in the process, each process is loading a file with 256MB, when I made the file as ```global``` the issue is resolved. Thanks for replying @EmilianoMartinez.